# AES Encryption in C# and Decryption in JS using crypto-js

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

**UseCase:**
I am developing a service that is in C# and I have to send an encrypted string to a different system that is already coded in JS using CryptoJS which will be decrypting the string I am going to be sending.
The receiving system is not going to make any changes to its implementation. They have shared the JS code they are using to DECRYPT along with the required credentials that I would need for my encryption.

**JS code of both Encrypt and Decrypt from the receiver**

```
var message = "hello world!!!";

function generateKey(salt, passPhrase, keySize, iterationCount) {
const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passPhrase, CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(salt), {
keySize: keySize / 32,
iterations: iterationCount
});
return key;
}

function Encrypt(cipherText) {
const salt = "DUMMYSALT-VALUE-of-Size-32CHARACTERS";
const iv ="DUMMYIV-VALUE-of-Size-32CHARACTERS";
const passPhrase = "SomeSecretPassPhrase";
const keySize = 128
const iterationCount = 1
const key = generateKey(salt, passPhrase, keySize, iterationCount);
const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(cipherText, key, {
iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv)
});
return encrypted.ciphertext.toString();
}

function Decrypt(cipherText, pass = "SomeSecretPassPhrase") {
const salt = "DUMMYSALT-VALUE-of-Size-32CHARACTERS";
const iv ="DUMMYIV-VALUE-of-Size-32CHARACTERS";
const passPhrase = "SomeSecretPassPhrase";
const keySize = 128
const iterationCount = 1
const key = generateKey(salt, passPhrase, keySize, iterationCount);

const cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(cipherText)
});
const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherParams, key, {
iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv)
});
return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}


var encrypted = Encrypt(message);
//equivalent to CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(message), key);
var decrypted = Decrypt(encrypted);
                                                        

$('#1').text("Encrypted: "+encrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
$('#2').text("Decrypted: "+decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

Output
Encrypted: 24a935f11a3e0b35dd6604cd7dbee292
Decrypted: hello world!!!

Question: While I try to port this over the C# and try to encrypt a string using the below, my encrypted value is different and also the JS code is unable to decrypt it.

**my code to encrypt:**

```
var MyKey = GenerateKey("DUMMYSALT-VALUE-of-Size-32CHARACTERS", "SomeSecretPassPhrase");
var EncryptedString = EncryptString(MyKey, "hello world!!!");


   public byte[] GenerateKey(string saltVal, string passphrase)
        {
            byte[] salt = ConvertHexStringToByteArray("DUMMYSALT-VALUE-of-Size-32CHARACTERS");
            int iterations = 1;
            var rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passphrase, salt, iterations);
            byte[] key = rfc2898.GetBytes(16);
            
            return key;
        }

        public string EncryptString(byte[] key, string stringToEncrypt )
        {
            AesManaged aesCipher = new AesManaged();
            aesCipher.KeySize = 128;
            aesCipher.BlockSize = 128;
            aesCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aesCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aesCipher.Key = key;
            aesCipher.IV = ConvertHexStringToByteArray("DUMMYPRESETIV-VALUE-of-Size-32CHARACTERS");
            byte[] b = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
            ICryptoTransform encryptTransform = aesCipher.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] ctext = encryptTransform.TransformFinalBlock(b, 0, b.Length);
            System.Console.WriteLine("IV:" + Convert.ToBase64String(aesCipher.IV));           
            System.Console.WriteLine("Cipher text: " + Convert.ToBase64String(ctext));
            return Convert.ToBase64String(ctext);
        }

        public byte[] ConvertHexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
        {
            int NumberChars = hexString.Length;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
                bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i, 2), 16);
            return bytes;
        }
```

I am not sure if am doing the correct equivalent of the JS method CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse()
,

Comment: The `Encrypt()` method in the JavaScript code returns the ciphertext hex encoded, while the `EncryptString()` method returns the ciphertext Base64 encoded. Apart from that, both codes produce the same ciphertext when the same input data is used (same salt, IV, passphrase, plaintext). Note that a static salt and IV are insecure and an iteration count of 1 is generally too low.

Comment: @Topaco : WOW!! that exactly was the issue. I was spending too much time trying to understand the Key generation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I still don't get how to "hide" the static salt and IV... I could generate a random value for both, but how could c# know those random values?